# Gulp JS doesn't output CSS file

Tags: javascript, gulp

I'm a Gulp JS beginner. Currently I'm trying to compile some simple less code to CSS. My Gulp task should output a new CSS file for this but after I run the task, nothing happens. I've included the gulp-util module to try to debug the task execution but it doesn't show me any errors.

Here's my Gulp file:

```
// gulpfile.js

// --- INIT
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    util = require('gulp-util'),
    less = require('gulp-less'), // compiles less to CSS
    minify = require('gulp-minify-css'), // minifies CSS
    concat = require('gulp-concat'),
    rename = require('gulp-rename'),
    uglify = require('gulp-uglify'); // minifies JS

// Paths variables
var paths = {
    'dev': {
        'less': './laravel/public/assets/less/'
    },
    'assets': {
        'css': './laravel/public/assets/css/ ',
        'js': './laravel/public/assets/js/',
        'vendor': './laravel/public/assets/bower_vendor/'
    }

};

// --- TASKS

// Auth CSS
gulp.task('auth.css', function(){
   return gulp.src(paths.dev.less + 'auth.less')
       .pipe(less().on('error', util.log))
       .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.assets.css))
       .pipe(minify({keepSpecialComments:0}))
       .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
       .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.assets.css));
});

// --- WATCH

// --- DEFAULT
gulp.task('default', ['auth.css']);
```

I'm using Laravel 4. This file lives in the root directory. I have changed the paths but that doesn't seem to work either. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the extra space at the end of your `path.assets.css`.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I just discovered the problem. I removed "./laravel" from the path, now it works.

Comment: No problem, glad its sorted.

Answer (score 0):

Just fixed. It seems, the path had to be something like: "./public/assets/css/". Now the file has been generated.